# How to get id value against headerValue="Select" in struts 2 using enum

Tags: javascript, java, enums, struts2

I've a list which I'm getting from DB hit. I'm showing that list using s:select struts 2 attribute and using default headerValue as 'Select'

```
    <s:select name="identification_type" id="identificationId"
        headerKey="" headerValue="Select"
        key="channeluser.label.user.identification.type"
        list="identification_List" listKey="enumId" listValue="description"
        onchange="loadIdentificationType()" required="true">
        <s:param name="labelcolspan" value="%{2}" />
        <s:param name="inputcolspan" value="%{2}" />
    </s:select>

    <s:textfield name="crn" maxlength="15"
        key="channeluser.label.identification.type.crn" id="crnId" required="true">
        <s:param name="labelcolspan" value="%{2}" />
        <s:param name="inputcolspan" value="%{2}" />
    </s:textfield>

    <s:textfield name="sln" maxlength="50"
        key="channeluser.label.identification.type.sln" id="slnId" required="true">
        <s:param name="labelcolspan" value="%{2}" />
        <s:param name="inputcolspan" value="%{2}" />
    </s:textfield>

    <s:textfield name="nationalId" maxlength="15"
        key="channeluser.label.identification.type.nid" id="nationalId" required="true">
        <s:param name="labelcolspan" value="%{2}" />
        <s:param name="inputcolspan" value="%{2}" />
    </s:textfield>
```

[How exactly it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyMFN.png)

Now based on what drop down i select , i find div id corresponding to crn, sln or spn mentioned above and putsome value operation within textfields.

[How it looks after selecting any drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2s0D.png)

Now my question is when i trace back to 'Select' or click 'Select' from any selected drop down, I'm not getting any id corresponding to 'Select' and thus not able to change previous values in text fields . Based on 'Select' id, i want to set previous values as ""/empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not quite clear what are you asking and what are you trying to achieve ... (just clarify the last part of your post). Now if I understand your problem correctly - couldn't  you track dropdowns with javascript, onSelect event and some internal variable?

Comment: I made question little tedious and got the solution. By default i can set the id using headerKey=-1 which solved my problem. Thanks @Plirkee